# Error loading a fixed JSON data to QML Listview on Component.onCompleted

Tags: qt, listview, qml

Considering the following QML prototype code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts

Item {
    id: test

    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 5

        color: "#FDFDFD"

        ListView {
            id: listView

            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height

            model: ListModel {
                ListElement {
                    name: "Loading..."
                }
            }

            delegate: Item {
                width: parent.width
                height: 50

                Row {
                    spacing: 10

                    Text {
                        text: code
                    }
                    Text {
                        text: name
                    }
                }
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                listView.model = [{"id":"1","code":"Code 1", "name":"Name 1",}]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors when running:

```
qrc:/components/Test.qml:1308371392: ReferenceError: code is not defined
qrc:/components/Test.qml:38:25: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:/components/Test.qml:35: ReferenceError: code is not defined
qrc:/components/Test.qml:38:25: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:/components/Test.qml:35: ReferenceError: code is not defined
qrc:/components/Test.qml:35: ReferenceError: code is not defined
```

`code` and `name` are defined in the JSON at the `Component.onCompleted` - it's a placeholder - later on I will inject database data here.

No data is shown on ListView - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem I believe is that you're initializing the model property with a ListModel that only uses `name` fields. In my experience, QML doesn't like it when you try to add roles to a model after you have created it.

Comment: In your "Loading..." ListElement, try adding `code: ""` or something and see if it works better.

Answer (score 0):

As @JarMan points, your original `ListModel` doesn't have `code`. It is always recommended the first element of your `ListModel` serves as a template for the number of elements to follow, so, if you have `"name"` and `"code"` this needs to be present.

Your are switching your `ListView.model` from a `ListModel` to a JavaScript array. Meaning your delegate needs to change from `model.name`, `model.code` to `modelData.name`, `modelData.code`. It's not recommended to switch types.

`ListModel.append` does support a JavaScript object as input, so, you can iterate over your JavaScript array calling `ListModel.append` iteratively.

In the following updated example, I added a placeholder `code: ""` to the first `ListElement` and when the `Timer` triggers, I call `clear()` and repopulate the `ListModel` with records from an array:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel {
            id: listModel
            ListElement { nameid:0; name: "Loading..."; code: "" }
        }
        delegate:  Row {
            spacing: 10
            Text { text: code }
            Text { text: name }
        }
    }
    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 1000
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            let arr = [
                 {"nameid":1,"code":"Code 1", "name":"Name 1"},
                 {"nameid":2,"code":"Code 2", "name":"Name 2"},
                 {"nameid":3,"code":"Code 3", "name":"Name 3"}
            ];
            listModel.clear();
            for (let e of arr) listModel.append(e);
        }
    }
    footer: Frame {
        Button {
            text: "Restart"
            onClicked: {
                listModel.clear();
                listModel.append( {"name":"Restarting..."} );
                timer.restart();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)